# Express.js - Mongoose multiple or conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I have a `userSchema` i have to search in the user records with a search key word

```
//userSchema 
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        city: String,
        postalCode: Number
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

So the API route is `localhost:3000/api/v1/search/:key` the key can be user name or city or postalCode, based on the key we have to get the results from collection.

this is what i have tried `userController`

```
index: async (req, res, next) => {

    const searchKey = req.params.key;

    const searchResult = await User.find({
        $or:[{name: searchKey},{city: searchKey},{postalCode: searchKey}]
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'query was succesfull',
        data: searchResult
    });
}
```

if i pass `:key` as **Canada** i am getting following error. if i pass `:key` as **123456** which is postalCode i am getting data

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to number failed for value \"Canada\" at path \"postalCode\" for model \"users\""
    }
}
```

So how do i make this query more robust so that based on the `:key` i have to get the data from user model

Looking for much needed help

Thank you.

Comment: Quick fix to try: `{postalCode: Number(searchKey)}`

Comment: @AndreiC thank you for your response, i tried that i'm getting error when i try to search Name and City by passing searchKey as String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the `userSchema` you declared `postalCode` as type of number, mongoose expect the `searchKey` to be number, try to build the query condition based on `searchKey` type:

```
// if searchKey is number
if ( parseInt(searchKey) ) {
    var condition = { postalCode: searchKey };
} else {
    var condition = { $or:[ { name: searchKey }, { city: searchKey }] };
}

const searchResult = await User.find(condition);
```

**Edit:** Use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) operator if you want to search by Word Similarities, but first you need to change `postalCode` type to string:

```
const searchResult = await User.find({
    $or:[ 
        { name: { $regex: new RegExp(searchKey, 'i') } },
        { city: { $regex: new RegExp(searchKey, 'i') } },
        { postalCode: { $regex: new RegExp(searchKey, 'i') } }
    ]
});
```

Comment: thank you for your time i really appreciate it, i tried you solution, it works only if i pass `:key` as integer but if i want to search **Name** and **City** i am getting following error `{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"postalCode\" for model \"users\""
    }
}`

Comment: It looks like mongoose consider `NaN` as string, I update my answer please take a look

Comment: perfect! that worked, just needed some inputs though, is it the ideal way to implement search query as in now if i enter the full code 123123 then only i will get the result is there a query where i enter only **12** then it list down all the postal code starting form **12**, or just **Ca** then list down all the city names starting from **Ca**

Comment: I think it's better to change postalCode type to string and use $regex operator if you want to search by word similarities, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{postalCode: isNaN(parseInt(searchKey)) ? undefined : parseInt(searchKey)}
```